# Where is flash.desktop package located

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

When I attempt to generate ASDocs for my Flex Air application, I get the following error:

```
 Error: Access of undefined property NativeDragManager.

                NativeDragManager.acceptDragDrop(this);

 Error: Access of undefined property ClipboardFormats.

                ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT
```

Both ClipboardFormats and NativeDragManager are located in the flash.desktop package. Do I have a .swc-file somewhere in my file system (Flex SDK?) that I can add to my build path to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect these files to be paRt of an AIR-related SWC; which should be located here:

```
[SDK Install Directory]\frameworks\libs\air
```

I'd say it is weird that ASDocs isn't finding this automatically; but ASDocs always seemed very buggy to me.